# Repeating CountIF in Google Sheets (loop a countif)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to reference 1 cell, and countif all comma-separated-variables within that cell. I want to do this in Google Sheets (not scripts).

Let's say Cell A1 = PK,COMP. I would want something like:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,REPT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,",")),COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,","))))
```

So in other words, the goal is to get this to loop. It would go through column B:B, count the number of times PK appears... then, next, it would go through column B:B and count the number of times COMP appears.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I agree with player0. Keep in mind that we cannot see your sheet, layout or data; and we don't come in understanding your end goal. So what may seem extremely clear to you (who has all of this at your disposal) is not clear from "out here" without seeing what you are seeing.